# Showing some input errors when used in GAMS software

Tags: gams-math

On working with GAMS software there shows some errors like dimension different ,illegal data element in the input part of code
SETS
i  /1*5/
j  /1*10/
k  /1*3/
l  /1*3/;

PARAMETERS
d(i,j) Distance between demand point i and installation j
/1 5 8 7 10 6 9 7 4 8
2 9 5 6 8 7 10 8 5 6
3 7 9 6 10 8 5 9 7 10
4 6 8 5 10 6 9 7 5 6
5 8 7 9 5 6 10 7 8 5/;

- Redefined table c_ij
  PARAMETER c_ij(i,j) Cost of delivering from demand point i to installation j
  /1.1 19 27 32 41 39 44 47 25 31 22
  2.1 38 25 22 31 40 47 22 30 36 20
  3.1 41 22 23 21 38 37 23 32 20 36
  4.1 22 41 45 47 44 20 33 46 23 40
  5.1 20 31 37 47 44 26 24 41 43 34/;

PARAMETER s_k(k) Maximum number of demand points in cluster k
/1 150
2 200
3 100/;

PARAMETER M Arbitrary large number /1000000/;

VARIABLES
x_ij(i,j) binary
y_kj(k,j) binary
t_ij(i,j) binary;

EQUATIONS
Demand_Point_Constraint(i)
Installation_Constraint(i,j)
Cluster_Size_Constraint(k)
Assignment_Constraint(j)
Distance_Constraint(i,j,k,l)
Delivery_Time_Constraint(i)
Delivery_Cost_Constraint(i,j)
Non_Negativity_Constraint;

Demand_Point_Constraint(i)..
sum(j, x_ij(i,j)) =e= 1;

Installation_Constraint(i,j)..
x_ij(i,j) =l= 1;

Cluster_Size_Constraint(k)..
sum(j, y_kj(k,j)) =l= 3;

Assignment_Constraint(j)..
sum(k, y_kj(k,j)) =e= 1;

Distance_Constraint(i,j,k,l)..
d_ij(i,j) =g= 5 * (1 - y_kj(k,j) - y_kj(l,j));

Delivery_Time_Constraint(i)..
sum(j, t_ij(i,j) * x_ij(i,j)) =l= 30;

Delivery_Cost_Constraint(i,j)..
c_ij(i,j) =e= 45 * d_ij(i,j) + 10 * (d_ij(i,j) - 1);

Non_Negativity_Constraint..
x_ij(i,j) =g= 0;
y_kj(k,j) =g= 0;

MODEL Facility_Location /all/;

Facility_Location.obj =
sum((i,j), c_ij(i,j) + 45 * d_ij(i,j) * t_ij(i,j) + 10 * (d_ij(i,j) - 1) * x_ij(i,j))
+ sum((k,j), s_k(k) * y_kj(k,j))
+ M * sum((i,j), t_ij(i,j));

SOLVE Facility_Location USING MIP MINIMIZING Facility_Location.obj;

DISPLAY x_ij, y_kj;

I want the minimised objective function which indicates whether store can be alloted on specified distance located stores by running the model